# Wordpress Divi Theme - Anchor link to accordion toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, accordion

I am trying to get an anchor link to direct to an accordion, and open the toggle.

I've found a code snippet on google that sort of works, but not entirely.

When I am on the page that the accordion is on, and I click on the anchor link, it correctly scrolls to the accordion and opens the tab --- however, it refreshes the page at this time and does not stay where the accordion is.

If I click on the anchor link from another page other than the one that the accordion is on, all it does is direct me to that page -- not the accordion.

Any assistance with the would be great.

The URL is http://casafamilyserv.wpengine.com/resources/

The anchor link is the 'Make a donation' button in the upper right hand corner of the page.

here is the JS snippet:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
    //accordion
    $('.menu-item-98 a').on('click', function(event){
        $('#my-accordion .et_pb_accordion_item_2 .et_pb_toggle_title').click();
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#my-accordion').offset().top }, 1000);
    });
});

</script>
```

The anchor link is to open the 'contribute / donate' accordion tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `return false;`.

```
$('.menu-item-98 a').on('click', function(event){
    // sometimes you may also need to add
    // event.preventDefault();

    donateScroll();

    return false;
});
```

This is happening because your donate button has a `#donate` in the url.

```
<a href="/resources#donate">Make A Donation</a>
```

By default, browsers will try to find `id="donate"` somewhere on the page and jump to it. Adding `return false;` blocks that default behavior and allows your js to have full control over the click event.

You can also add something to check for existing hash when arriving from a different page:

```
function donateScroll(){
    $('#my-accordion .et_pb_accordion_item_2 .et_pb_toggle_title').click();
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#my-accordion').offset().top }, 1000);
}

if(window.location.hash == '#donate') {
    donateScroll();
}
```

Instead of repeating your scroll and click logic, you can also move it into a reusable function.

Comment: thank you for the help and clarification -- adding the return false stopped the page from refreshing when the button is clicked -- however, if I click on the button from a different page other than the page the accordion is on, it will just load the page and won't jump to the accordion. When I added the event.preventDefault(); it stopped the button from clicking all together.

Comment: almost there! It now loads the page and scrolls down, but it does not open the accordion toggle

Comment: Wrap the if statement with hash check into $(function() { }); to wait for the page to finish loading before executing anything else.

Comment: I'm having the same issue pertaining to a different website, where i have more than one link to open a tab (instead of accordion). I've got almost everything down and working smoothly, except for the code only works when I'm on the page it's calling to. If I click on the anchor link for a different page it does not work. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @Trisha I think you should open a new question for that.

Comment: I just opened a new question, if you would like to take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861539/wordpress-divi-theme-anchor-link-opens-tab-toggle