# Wordpress Divi Theme - Anchor link opens tab toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to get anchor links to open up tabs on a specific page.

When I am on the page that the tabs are on, and I click on the anchor link, it correctly scrolls to the tab and opens it --- however, if I am on a different page than the tabs are on, the anchor link only goes to that page, it does not open the tab.

URL: http://elkodowntown.wpengine.com/

The Anchor links are under the **OUR MEMBERS** menu in the navigation.

JS:

```
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('.menu-item-179 a').on('click', function(event){
            tabScroll('.et_pb_tab_0');
            return false;
        });
        $('.menu-item-180 a').on('click', function(event){
            tabScroll('.et_pb_tab_1');
            return false;
        });
        $('.menu-item-181 a').on('click', function(event){
            tabScroll('.et_pb_tab_2');
            return false;
        });
        $('.menu-item-182 a').on('click', function(event){
            tabScroll('.et_pb_tab_3');
            return false;
        });
        $('.menu-item-183 a').on('click', function(event){
            tabScroll('.et_pb_tab_4');
            return false;
        });

    function tabscroll(target) {
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#member-tabs').offset().top }, 1000);
        setTimeout($('#member-tabs' + target + ' a').click(), 2000 );
    }

    $(function hash() {
        var hash = window.location.hash.replace('#', "");

        if (hash == '#shop') { tabscroll('.et_pb_tab_1'); }
        if (hash == '#service') { tabscroll('.et_pb_tab_0'); }
        if (hash == '#eat-drink') { tabscroll('.et_pb_tab_2'); }
        if (hash == '#arts-entertainment') { tabscroll('.et_pb_tab_3'); }
        if (hash == '#stay') { tabscroll('.et_pb_tab_4'); }
    });
});
```

Anchor Links HTML:

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-179" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-179"><a href="/our-members#shop">Shop</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-180" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-180"><a href="/our-members#service">Service</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-181" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-181"><a href="/our-members#eat-drink">Eat &amp; Drink</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-182" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-182"><a href="/our-members#arts-entertainment">Arts &amp; Entertainment</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-183" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-183"><a href="/our-members#stay">Stay</a></li>
</ul>
```

Tabs HTML:

```
<div id="member-tabs" class="et_pb_module et_pb_tabs  et_pb_tabs_0 et_slide_transition_to_3 et_slide_transition_to_0">
                <ul class="et_pb_tabs_controls clearfix">
                    <li class="et_pb_tab_0 et_pb_tab_active"><a href="#">Shop</a></li><li class="et_pb_tab_1"><a href="#">Service</a></li><li class="et_pb_tab_2"><a href="#">Eat &amp; Drink</a></li><li class="et_pb_tab_3"><a href="#">Arts &amp; Entertainment</a></li><li class="et_pb_tab_4"><a href="#">Stay</a></li>
                </ul>
```

The anchor links (#shop,#service, etc) are being called by `<a name="#shop">` here (directly under the Tabs HTML):

```
<div class="et_pb_tab clearfix et_pb_active_content et_pb_tab_0 et-pb-active-slide" style="z-index: 1; display: block; opacity: 1;">
    <a name="shop"></a><!--- tab content here --->
</div>
```

I'm sure there is a better way to organize my JS.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You have multiple `tabScroll` functions, which should really be a single function that passes in a target as a parameter. That shouldn't affect your question though. As for your question, this may not be the answer, but your jQuery `tabScroll` functions are clicking the target links *before* attempting to scroll to them? Would that not redirect before a scroll anyway? I would attempt to swap those two around, and then put the click in a `setTimeout` of the same length as the scrolling animation :)

Comment: @obsidian - I'm not sure that I fully understand your comment. Should it look like this ?? `$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#member-tabs').offset().top }, 1000);
setTimeout($('#member-tabs .et_pb_tab_1 a').click(); );`

Comment: Yes, that is what I was referring to. You're using jQuery to click those target links before running the animation that scrolls to them -- I'm surprised that you see the scroll at all :) Of course, the scroll takes time (1 second) in your current code, so you may also need to **delay** the click event by a second, by wrapping it in a `setTimeout`. That's just a theory though, not necessarily the solution ;)

Comment: @obsidian, here is what I have: `$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#member-tabs').offset().top }, 1000);   setTimeout($('#member-tabs .et_pb_tab_1 a').click(), 2000 );`

Comment: I think I have the solution -- bear with me :)

Comment: I still haven't found a workaround for this, and @Obsidian Age has stopped responding. If anyone would like to help, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

After looking through the code for a while, the problem finally dawned on me. You currently wrap each of the click handlers inside their own jQuery function:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.menu-item-183 a').on('click', function(event){
        tabScroll();
        return false;
    });
    function tabScroll(){
        $('#member-tabs .et_pb_tab_4 a').click();
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#member-tabs').offset().top }, 1000);
    }
});
jQuery(function($) { ...
```

In each of these contexts, `tabscroll()` only has scope relative to the outer jQuery function. That is to say, in the above context, *only* `menu-item-183` will have access to *that particular* `tabscroll()` function.

You later try to reference the `tabscroll()` function outside of that scope:

```
$(function hash() {
  var hash = window.location.hash.replace('#', "");
  if (hash == '#shop') { tabscroll(); }
  if (hash == '#service') { tabscroll(); }
  if (hash == '#eat-drink') { tabscroll(); }
  if (hash == '#arts-entertainment') { tabscroll(); }
  if (hash == '#stay') { tabscroll(); }
});
```

As this block reads, all conditionals are trying to do the exact same thing (call `tabscroll()` with no given parameter), and the condition could essentially be written as:

```
if (hash == '#shop' || hash == '#service' || ... ) {
  tabscroll();
}
```

But you need the `tabscroll` function to redirect to different locations that **aren't the same as `hash`**, which means you have to manually separate them out:

```
if (hash == '#shop') { tabscroll('.et_pb_tab_1'); }
if (hash == '#service') { tabscroll('.et_pb_tab_0'); }
if (hash == '#eat-drink') { tabscroll('.et_pb_tab_2'); }
if (hash == '#arts-entertainment') { tabscroll('.et_pb_tab_3'); }
if (hash == '#stay') { tabscroll('.et_pb_tab_4'); }
```

Then simply change your tabscroll function to allow for this:

```
function tabscroll(target) {
  $('#member-tabs' + target + ' a').click();
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#member-tabs').offset().top }, 1000);
}
```

The final step is to make sure that this **new** `tabscroll()` function is accessible from your condition. With your current code structure, it should be placed just above or below `$(function hash() {});`

Ultimately you should restructure your code so that every click links to this new `tabscroll()` function, but this should be enough to solve the problem for now :)

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I'm doing something wrong. I've updated my JS in my question above.

Comment: I don't understand your use of (target) and + target + in the code. am I to replace that with the .et_pb_tab_ classes? Don't I need to define the target?

Comment: There's two problems with your updated code -- first, you updated your main links to the new structure I recommended, but forgot to pass through `target` in each of those tabscrolls. For example, `$('.menu-item-179 a').on('click', function(event){` must call `tabscroll('.et_pb_tab_1');`. Your second problem is that you're using `setTimeout($('#member-tabs + target + a')` instead of `setTimeout($('#member-tabs' + target + ' a')` -- you need to make sure the JavaScript variable `target` isn't passed as a string :)

Comment: My use of `target` in the function is essentially just passing through a variable to a function. Whatever you pass **to** `tabscroll()` **becomes** `target`, allowing you to inject different code for different scenarios (you want different targets in your example). For example, `tabscroll('.et_pb_tab_1')` call will have a `target` equivalent to `.et_pb_tab_1`, while `tabscroll('.et_pb_tab_0')` will have a `target` equivalent to `.et_pb_tab_0`. Hope that helps in your understanding :)

Comment: It's not working because you haven't followed my solution correctly :) Make the two updates I stated in my comments, and it will work correctly. If not, revert to your original code, and **only** apply my answer, rather than changing the structure of you clicks as well.

Comment: I've updated my code with the two updates, and it still isn't working :(  there are no errors in the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134032/discussion-between-trisha-and-obsidian-age).